# Why does static library contain a main function?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, program-entry-point

I came across a weird static library which contains a **`main()`** function (C++).
I just wonder what the purpose it is.

How does the `main()` execute?

Comment: It gets executed like any main? (There can only be one anyway) As for its purpose why not ask the author of the library?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the linker perspective, it doesn't matter where the `main` function is - it can be in a static library as well as in standalone object file, linker couldn't care less. It produces the executable from object files, no matter where they come from, and in the final executable all the distinction between library/non library symbols is lost.

As for the purposes, i can imagine that some sort of specialized application framework could have main in the library, with you providing callbacks to it in form of defined functions.

Comment: SDL does this--its `main` provides cross-platform setup and teardown code. When the user types `main` after `#include`ing SDL it's actually a macro that expands to `SDL_main`, which is called from `main` when everything is properly initialized. That provides another use case, though I've seen a fair amount of criticism for this approach.

Comment: @jaggedSpire, didn't know about this, but yes, this is a reason as well. However, macro to redefine `main` is a pure evil in my view.

Comment: yep, that was the main criticism I saw (no pun intended), and it's bit me before as well. Fortunately, they let you force the use of your own entry point, but it comes with the downside of less coherent error messages when things go wrong. Fun stuff all around, really.

Answer (score 10):

> I just wonder what the purpose it is.

It's a common technique with unit testing or graphics/game engine frameworks to define the `main()` entry point of the executable program, and binding the custom class definitions from certain factory pattern templates.

> how does the `main()` execute?

It is the main entry point of any c++ program by definition, so the execution is triggered by the program start up linker script.

---

Using such stuff means you write your client classes in an executable project, bind them with the framework, and omit to define a `main()` function.

Comment: What your answer describes is the Inversion of control, or IoC development  pattern used by frameworks like Spring Boot. This is where it gets it's name, from the fact that when compared to the classic library pattern, it is the exact equal/opposite. In other words, it is the same pattern, but the library (framework) acts as the application, and the app just defines the configurations and gives values / implementation. Now it gets a bit more complicated, but that was the original idea.