# Main function in a static library

Tags: cmake, static-libraries

Is it possible that the main function was in a static library? For example, I don't want to include headers that are used in the main function in another project. If yes, then how can I describe it in **CMake** so that the project can be built, and if not, what are the options?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Is it possible that the main function was in a static library?" - Yes, a library could define `main` function like any other function. Have you tried that? See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514935/why-does-static-library-contain-a-main-function).